# How is indexOf returning the position of this example, shouldn't the result be -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, indexof

I know that `indexOf` searches the position of a value in a string / array then returns the position but I thought the it must be an exact match even if there's spaces.  But I was reading this and I am confused why it's returning true even if the match is only partial.

Normally this is how indexOf would return and as expected

```
var array = ["AA", "BB", "A", "CC", "D", "This is the time to be back home.", "It's christmas"];
// Let's say result >= 0 will return true else false
console.log(array.indexOf("AA") + " AA");   // 0 --true
console.log(array.indexOf("A") + " A");     // 2 --true
console.log(array.indexOf("C") + " C");     // -1 --false
console.log(array.indexOf("DD") + " DD");   // -1 --false
console.log(array.indexOf("the time") + " the time");   // -1 --false
console.log(array.indexOf("It's christmas") + " christmas");    // 6 --true
```

and this is what I saw in a book and don't understand why it's returning true meaning it's found in the array.

```
String.prototype.cliche = function(){
    var cliche = ["lock and load", "touch base", "open the kimono"];

    for (var i = 0; i < cliche.length; i++){
        var index = this.indexOf(cliche[i]);
        if(index >= 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var sentences = ["I'll send my car around to pick you up.",
                "Let's touch base in the morning and see where we are",
                "We don't want to open the kimono, we just want to inform them."];

for(var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++){
    var phrase = sentences[i];
    if(phrase.cliche()){
        console.log("CLICHE ALERT: " + phrase);
    }
}
```

the cliche array in the function only has partial of the phrase like `touch base` and so on

but in the sentence array the value is like `Let's touch base in the morning and see where we are` the `indexOf` actually returns true for this one even if it's only partial of the phrase matches the cliche value.

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because they are different methods:

- `Array.prototype.indexOf` returns the first position where some value is found (using strict equality algorithm) in an array.
- `String.prototype.indexOf` returns the first position where some string is contained (is a substring) in a string.

Example:

```
["AA"].indexOf("A"); // -1 (not found)
"AA".indexOf("A");   // 0
```